# Checkboxes when created dynamically not getting checked/unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I want on my web page, a list of checkboxes with links in front.

Here is a code that i am using

```
//data is json object
var htmlCode = "<ul>";
$.each(data, function(index, value) {
   htmlCode = htmlCode + "<div><input type='checkbox'/><a href='#'>"+value+"</a></div>";
});
htmlCode= htmlCode + "</ul>"
```

It creates checkboxes links beside it however, i am just able to check an uncheck first checkbox in that list.

Why is it so? How can i get all checkboxes to be responsive?

Comment: on your change event use event delegation.

Comment: some like this $(document).on('change','.classofcheckbox',function(){//code here})

Comment: did you try my comment? change you your change event to like that?